# Using the Affine cipher, do we need $a^{-1}$ if we know gcd(a,26)=1?

Tags: inverse, cryptography, euclidean-algorithm, inverse-function, inverse-problems

I have just attempted the affine cipher with the word "code"

$CODE = 02140304$

Lets choose our key as $(5,3)$, so our encryption is $y=5x+3$

$13211823=NVSX$

Now, to undo the code, I would have to do the euclidian algorithm to find $a^{-1} $ so I can say $x=a^{-1}(y-b)$, however why can't I just do $x=\frac{y-b}{a}$ to get $x$ without the use of the euclidian algorithm.

Comment: They are equivalent, how do you compute $\frac{21-3}5\equiv14\pmod{26}$ otherwise?

Comment: You can do the division step, however, unless $y-b$ is divisible by $a$, you will end up with a fraction, which is undesirable. To fix this you can find $1/a$, i.e. $a^{-1}$, by the EEA in integer form, keeping nice integers in your mod 26 world.

Comment: My confusion is coming from the fact that it seems like it should be simple algebra, to encode x it's ax+b, and to decode it we subtract b leaving us with ax, why then can't i divide by a? Cold you show and example of a word?

Comment: Have i just "got lucky" with this example?

Answer (score 1):

$5$ is relatively prime to $26$. This means that $5^{-1}$ exists modulo 26.

This allows us to solve all equations $5x = b$ (for all $b$), namely by multiplying both sides with $5^{-1}$: $x = 5^{-1} \cdot 5 x = 5^{-1} \cdot b$.

Division is just multiplication with the inverse. Writing division as you do, suggests working in the rationals, which is not what we're doing here. We multiply by the inverse instead (if it exists, but 5 was chosen wisely: we cannot use even numbers and 13 as these have no inverse).

To compute $5^{-1}$ use the extended Euclidean algorithm, and write $1 = \gcd(5,26)$ as $1 = 5c + 26d$, $c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$, so $5c \equiv 1 \bmod{26}$, and $c = 5^{-1}$.